# Limit giving indeterminate result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

I have a function $r_h(v)$ given by,

$$r_h (v) = \left(\frac{m_0}{2 g} e^{-g v_f} \left(-1+e^{-g(v - v_f)} \right) \right)^{1/5}$$

where $m_0$ and $g$ are just numbers. I want to take the limits of some expression involving $r_h$ which are written in the code below. In particular, I want to take $v \rightarrow v_f$ and in the code I wrote it like that. In the actual physical problem I'm considering $v_f \rightarrow \infty$, although I think I don't have to impose $v_f \rightarrow \infty$ in the code when taking the limit as long as taking $v \rightarrow v_f$ will already converge to an answer.

The issue is that I'm getting a result of `Indeterminate` but I'm expecting the limits to give 0, so how should I resolve this issue? I have looked into some other threads but I cannot find a solution.

````
rh[v_] := ((m0/(2 g)) Exp[-g vf] (-1 + Exp[-g (v - vf)]))^(1/5)
h[v_] := Exp[-Integrate[(m0 Exp[-g v])/(((m0/(2 g)) Exp[-g vf] (-1 + Exp[-g (v - vf)]))^2)^(1/5), v]]
fdp[v] = -3 D[rh[v], v]/rh[v]^2 + 1;
fp[v] = Integrate[fdp[v], v];

Limit[(rh[v] h[v] (D[rh[v], v])^2 - rh[v]^3 h[v] D[rh[v], v] ) /. {g -> 3, m0 -> 10}, v -> vf]

Limit[(rh[v]^2 h[v]^2 (D[rh[v], v])^2 fp[v]) /. {g -> 3, m0 -> 10}, v -> vf]

Limit[(rh[v]^3 h[v] D[rh[v], v]) /. {g -> 3, m0 -> 10}, v -> vf]

Indeterminate
```
````

Comment: If you don't do the `Limit` and just look carefully at the result of each of your last three expressions then you see many examples of `(-1+E^(3(v-vf))))` which is `-1+E^0` which is `0` and that gives you LOTS of zeros in both numerators and denominators. Thus I'm guessing each of those approach infinity from one side and -infinity from the other side and that is why `Limit` is saying the result is `Indeterminant` Makes sense now? If you look at the docs for `Limit` you might be able to see how to find the limit from the left and then the limit from the right and confirm my guess about this.

Comment: e.g. `Limit[1/x, x -> 0, Direction -> #] & /@ {"FromAbove", "FromBelow"}`